# Streaming with Canon XA10, Black Magic Intensity Shuttle, and StreamLabs OBS on Windows 10

Tags: video, hdmi, video-conversion, video-streaming

I am attempting to Live Stream with my [Canon XA10](https://www.usa.canon.com/internet/portal/us/home/products/details/camcorders/professional/xa10/) using a [BlackMagic Intensity Shuttle](https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/products/intensity) and [StreamLabs OBS](https://streamlabs.com/). I can't seem to get a picture in either the BM Desktop Video, BM Media Express, or OBS.  I see the Intensity Shuttle in the Device Manager (says it is working properly).  B< Desktop Video recognizes the shuttle, and so does StreamLabs OBS.  However, all I get is a black screen. I am not getting any picture.  I have the HDMI Output turned on the Canon XA10. The Video Output states it is 1920 X 1080p. I have tried matching all kinds of video settings (e.g. 1080p30) and still I get no video.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why, but when I turned off HDMI Output, it works!  HDMI Output turned on pushes 1920 X 1080p - turned off it does 1920 X 1080i   and it works for me. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

hope this is not too late but I've been using Black Magic Intensity with OBS for at least 5 years now and the best solution I got was to download Black Syphon and select your video resolution in the Input preview dropdown on the right.

In OBS, add Syphon Client as a source and in the properties window select Black Syphon.